# ListView item Click/Tap programmatically

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a custom selector for my ListView items. This is what it looks like:

```
<item android:drawable="@color/transparent" android:state_activated="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/blue" android:state_activated="true"/>
```

When I tap on an item, it's background turns blue. I want to do this "tapping" via code but I don't know what method to call even if I already know the child's position in ListView.

---

Actually, what I really want is to change the background of a row (similar to when it is tapped) without firing onListItemClick().

Answer (score 2):

> I want to do this "tapping" via code

Fetch the row that you want (it must be on the screen) and call [`performClick()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#performClick%28%29) or maybe you can use [`setActivated(true)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setActivated%28boolean%29) (I've never tried this method.)

Comment: But performclick() doesn't take the row position as a parameter. I've tried performItemClick() but I just calls my onListItemClickListener without changing the background. I've also tried setActivated(true) but still no effect.

Comment: Try `listView.setItemChecked(position, true);`

Answer (score 0):

What if you tried emulating a touch event? Perhaps not the cleanest answer, but...

Get your desired row's view then call

```
rowView.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 0, 0, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your selector to toggle on `android:state_selected="true"`, then use `listView.setSelection(index)`;

Comment: How do I change the selector to toggle?

Comment: `<item android:drawable="@color/blue" android:state_selected="true"/>`

`<item android:drawable="@color/transparent"/>`